# looping through mysql table data

Tags: mysql, function, select, stored-procedures

I have a mysql table 'table1' with data

```
id      mailid  currentstatus   assignedto  assignedtime       logtime
4338    14928   assigned           user1    4/15/2013 13:44    4/15/2013 13:44
4352    14928   followup           user1    4/15/2013 13:44    4/15/2013 13:50
16297   14928   assigned           user1    4/15/2013 13:44    4/29/2013 9:52
16300   14928   replied            user1    4/15/2013 13:44    4/29/2013 9:55
5731    15710   assigned           user2    4/17/2013 10:16    4/17/2013 10:17
5769    15710   followup           user2    4/17/2013 10:16    4/17/2013 10:35
16281   15710   assigned           user2    4/17/2013 10:16    4/29/2013 9:40
16291   15710   replied            user2    4/17/2013 10:16    4/29/2013 9:48
```

i want to find out the time spent by each user on each mailid.

Explanation of the columns:

- id: (Auto Increment Column)
- mailid: (Unique ID for an e-mail)
- currentstatus: (Current Status of the Mail)
- assignedto: (Username to whom the e-mail is assigned to)
- assignedtime: (Date and time the e-mail was assigned)
- logtime: (Date and Time of insert of the row, i.e. date and time of the currentstatus)

The id 4338 and 5731 are the first row for mailid 14928 and 15710 respectively and the last row for these ids are 16300 and 16291 which will always have currentstatus as 'replied'.

Here, i need the output wherein

> (logtime of 4352 - logtime of 4338) + (logtime of 16300 - logtime of
>   16297)

This will give me the time spent by user1 on mailid 14928.

What is common here:

1. the column currentstatus for the last row will always be 'replied'
2. each row to be subtracted with the preceding 'assigned' in currentstatus

How is the table updated:

This is a part of an e-mail management solution wherein e-mails are assigned to the users and users can either reply to the e-mail or put it in followup and reply later.

In both the cases below, the users have been assigned an e-mail (14928 and 15710). Both the users had placed these e-mails in followup and when they had to reply to this e-mail, these e-mails were re-assigned and then replied.

Please help!

The desired output is:

```
mailid  assignedto  timespent
14928   user1       00:08:55
15710   user2       00:26:57
```

So far i am able to write the below query, however, need to optimize this query.

```
SELECT mailid,
       assignedto,
       sum(st) TimeSpent
FROM
  ( SELECT b.*,
    CASE WHEN b.currentstatus = 'assigned' 
           THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, b.logtime, (SELECT a.logtime
                                                   FROM inbox_log a
                                                   WHERE a.mailid = b.mailid
                                                   AND a.logtime > b.logtime
                                                   ORDER BY a.table1 LIMIT 1))
           ELSE 0
     END st
   FROM table1 b
   WHERE logtime >= '2013-04-25') d
GROUP BY mailid,
         assignedto;
```

> Apologies, could not create a fiddle since facing problems with
>   http://sqlfiddle.com

This query takes approx 150 seconds for 16,000 rows. Any suggestions how i can optimize this query

Comment: @Satya, I have tried creating a procedure looping through the rows, but had no luck...

Comment: How about doing  it with the programming language you are using ?

Comment: @jimy, i am using php. In fact i am working on the same. I will post once i get the desired output. However, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: will a mailid be always assigned to the same userid?

Comment: yes @didierc, a mailid once assigned will be assigned to the same userid

Comment: Your dates aren't really in that format, right?

Comment: @Strawberry, i have posted a workaround. Please help me optimize the query!

Comment: But the workaround's a mess. I think it's better to start again.

Comment: yes @Strawberry, That is true. Well the dates are in mysql format... its just that i copied the table from excel the dates are in excel format in the above question

Comment: @Satya, i have edited my question of what i have tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Chitranjan Thakur, i am not able to optimize the query. below is the function that i created.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION <function-name>(mailidparam INT) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
  DECLARE bdone,
          abc BOOL;
  DECLARE mt VARCHAR(150);
  DECLARE lt DATETIME;
  DECLARE tstart,
          tend DATETIME;
  DECLARE taht INT;
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
  SELECT
    il.currentstatus,
    il.logtime
  FROM table1 il
  WHERE il.mailid = mailidparam
  ORDER BY il.logtime;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = TRUE;
  OPEN curs;
  SET bDone = FALSE;
  SET taht = 0;
  SET tend = NULL;
read_loop:
LOOP
  FETCH curs INTO mt, lt;
  IF bdone THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;
  IF (mt = 'assigned') THEN
    SET tstart = lt;
  ELSE
    SET tend = lt;
    SET taht := taht + TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tstart, tend);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
  CLOSE curs;
  RETURN taht;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and the query as

```
SELECT 
  *,
  get_mailid_aht (il.mailid) aht 
FROM
  table1 il 
WHERE il.currentstatus = 'replied' ;
```

The previous working used to take approx 125 seconds, however after implementing the function it was taking approx 108 seconds which was not a great achievement.

> However, adding the index of mailid, currentstatus and logtime worked
>   like magic and now the query runs in 3.023 seconds.

**Thanks to the StackOverflow members who are always here to help!**

Answer (score 1):

#### Hey you can optimize it by using “function”:

Firstly you need to create a function which will result you only those records on which you want to perform action.

**Syntax:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_name ([func_parameter[,...]]) RETURNS type routine_body
```

**Example**

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE FUNCTION hello_world(addressee TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT
      LANGUAGE SQL -- This element is optional and will be omitted from subsequent examples
    BEGIN
      RETURN CONCAT('Hello ', addressee);
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Execute as follows:**

```
mysql> SELECT hello_world('Earth');
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will take lesser time and will work for you.

Comment: Thanks! i am able to optimize the query with your help

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer, however, need to optimize this query.

```
    select mailid, assignedto, sum(st) TimeSpent
    from
    (
    SELECT b.*, 
CASE WHEN b.currentstatus = 'assigned' 
   THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, b.logtime, 
     (SELECT a.logtime from inbox_log a 
      where a.mailid = b.mailid AND a.logtime > b.logtime ORDER BY a.table1 LIMIT 1))
  ELSE 0 END st from table1 b where logtime >= '2013-04-25'    
    ) d
    GROUP BY mailid, assignedto;
```

> Apologies, could not create a fiddle since facing problems with
>   http://sqlfiddle.com

This query takes approx 150 seconds for 16,000 rows. Any suggestions how i can optimize this query

Comment: Post this in your question instead. And add the result of `EXPLAIN your_query` so we know more about the execution.